# angularjs batarang not working with local files

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to run the batarang chrome extension without a web server. When loading a local file in chrome, the model simply doesn't show. I am running chrome with the --allow-file-access-from-files parameter and the angular application is running correctly. Also setting the options in the options tag is being reset by chrome to not checked. When running the extension   via a web server, everything works correctly. Does anyone know a way to run batarang locally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found this post while searching for answers for this same issue.

Seems like there is a issue related to local file handling int Batarang. As per this [github issue reply](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/65) easiest way to solve this is to use python SimpleHTTPServer to serve files locally.

Just run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in your folder and access the files using `localhost:8000/file.html`

Comment: Thanks. Figured this already out. I'm using nodejs to serve the files. Not much overhead involved.

Answer (score 8):

Select the checkbox 'Allow access to file URLs' in the extensions panel

Comment: Doesn't work. Running the exact same app on a production box and a localhost setup and batarang only shows up on the prod box.